# Logistics functions and values for pair of points.

Tags: statistics

I have a question to them:

I have the following pairs of points:

$(0.005, 1200),(0.015, 3500), (0.02, 4400), (0.025, 5000)$

How I can find the appropriate logistics function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

This problem is relevant to nonlinear curve fit (since there as more data points than parameters in the model).

The logistic function write $$y=\frac{L}{1+c e^{ax}}$$ and you need to determine the "best" values of unknown parameters $L,c,a$ which fit the data points. The difficulty for this kind of problems is to start the iterations from a reasonable guess.

Let us assume that we have a rough idea about the value of $L$ (which corresponds to the asymptote). If this is the case, we can rewrite $$\frac Ly -1=c e^{ax}$$ and taking logarithms $$z=\log\Big(\frac Ly -1)=\log(c)+ax=b +a x$$ and so parameters $b$ (then $c=e^b$) and $a$ can be estimated using standard linear regression.

Form the plot of the data you gave, let us guess $L=5500$ (above the largest value). Compute the $z_i$ for each $x_i$; perform the regression which gives you $b$ (then $c$) and $a$. All of that can easily be done with Excel.

Now, you have all elements for starting a nonlinear regression.

If you cannot perform nonlinear regression, what you could do is to define an error function $$\Phi(L)=\sum_{i=1}^4\Big(y_i-\frac{L}{1+c e^{ax_i}}\Big)^2$$ repeating the linear regression for different values of $L$ and plotting the results find a best value of $L$ which minimizes $\Phi(L)$. Again, all the work can be done with plain Excel.

To allow you to check your results, using $L=5500$, the above procedure leads to $a=-178.3$, $c=8.623$ and $\Phi(5500)=3199$. Find now the best values.

Comment: You are very welcome ! Cheers :-)